# Unable to insert data with non keyboard characters in Sharepoint using Python

Tags: python, sharepoint

I am parsing some JSON data and trying to insert in Share Point list through python module "Shareplum". But I am getting the error while inserting data having some special characters eg. 'È', 'É' .

The code snippet and the error details are below:

## Insert Data in SharePoint

sp_list.UpdateListItems(data=request_data_list, kind='New')

Error:

File "outletload.py", line 61, in 
    load_data(tps, tps_api_col, tps_sp_col, tps_up_date, tps_sp_list_name)
  File "outletload.py", line 41, in load_data
    sp_list.UpdateListItems(data=request_data_list, kind='New')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/shareplum/shareplum.py", line 648, in UpdateListItems
    soap_request.add_actions(data, kind)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/shareplum/shareplum.py", line 761, in add_actions
    field.text = str(value)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa8' in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 0):

Python 2 doesn't support unicode strings straight out of the box. You can tell python something is a unicode string by using the "u" keyword. Try the following:

```
request_data_list = {'1': u'È', '2': u'É'}
sp_list.UpdateListItems(data=request_data_list, kind='New')
```

You can find more info about this on this page (which contains an example with the same error you're having):
https://www.pythoncentral.io/python-unicode-encode-decode-strings-python-2x/